# How to define correctly dictionary with hexadecimal values?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex

I have an if-elif statement to assign hexadecimal value to the variable `BinValues` like this:

```py
if a == "v1":
    BinValues = b'\xF2'
elif a == "v2":
    BinValues = b'\xD3'
elif a == "v3":
    BinValues = b'\x71\xC2'
```

Since hex values could be greater than 3, instead to use several if statements, I want to use a dictionary for this task.

I've tried as below but a get error.

```py
BinValues  = { "v1": b'\xF2', "v2": b'\xD3', "v3": b'\x71\xC2' }
```

But when I print the content of dict `BinValues`, the value for key "v3" has changed to `b'q\xc2'` when the value I entered is `b'\x71\xC2'`

```py
>>> BinValues
{'v1': b'\xf2', 'v2': b'\xd3', 'v3': b'q\xc2'}
```

Whats is going on? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
b'\x71\xc2' == b'q\xc2'
```

since

```py
b'\x71' == b'q'
```

Checking the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), you can see that "**hex 71**" corresponds to "**q**".

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much for your answer and link shared

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be the same. Python is just showing as an ascii character. I dont know much about hex values but here you go. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html

I also tried writing to a file and got the same result except with a weird question mark character. It is the same since the hexadecimal value for `q` is `71`

Comment: Thanks for your help and info shared. In understand now